Strapi showing latest node version which is not even installed on my computer
0
I am trying to create a new strapi project in my api folder for an ecommerce website project. However no matter what I do to try to change the node version using nvm I still get this error (that it is not compatible to the current version). As you can see below I literally just used nvm to change the node version to 20.0.0 and I got confirmation I was currently using it. Also you can see on my nvm list command that 21.2.0 isn't even installed. I am confused and also a beginner. Am I using nvm wrong? Do I have to delete some previous folder that is somehow making my project think I am using 21.2.0? I am very confused and would appreciate any help.
current@0.1.6
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm current
v20.11.0
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm ls
20.9.0
20.5.0
20.0.0

PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> nvm use 20.0.0
Now using node v20.0.0 (64-bit)
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api> npx create-strapi-app@latest .
(node:14736) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternatiternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
? Choose your installation type Custom (manual settings)
You are running Node.js 21.2.0
Strapi requires Node.js >=18.0.0 <=20.x.x
Please make sure to use the right version of Node.
PS C:\Users\liamt\Desktop\ecommerce-app\api>
I tried to change the version of nod using nvm and it appeared to change however I still have the same error.
I updated the node version to 20 but not working although showing on cmd
